# Stop Magento "fixing" html in static blocks

Tags: magento, tinymce

Does anyone know if there's some way to stop Magento "fixing" html that's added via static blocks?

For example, if I wanted to have a space within an existing menu for adding static blocks to, I wouldn't want to use a full < ul > list as it already exists, so I'd just want some additional < li > tags within the block.

However, Magento *very helpfully* decides to always add in the "missing" < ul > tags for you. Rather annoying.

I've tried tracing this back myself but just can't find where it's happening. I think it could be TinyMce related, as the fixing happens if you hide/show the editor, without a page refresh. I tried changing different instances I found of cleanup:1 to cleanup:0 but none of them so far worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

It's not magento that is doing this cleanup but the wysiwyg editor : tiny_mce

You can desactivate this behavior by adding :

```
cleanup : false
```

in the js config file (js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js)

But this is totally not recommended as it can break all of your pages is an HTML bug is injected in a block or page and you don't have any other HTML tidier on your project ...

Comment: Yeah, was just reading something similar on the tiny mce faqs. I guess the best bet then is to create a new widget template to be used there, that can contain the needed elements for the menu already.

Comment: I would just replace/overload the js file (included in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml) only for the cms_block controller. nothing more :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the tinymce configuration parameter [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) and [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children).
You can define `li`-tags as valid elements there and define that `li`-tags may be childs to other thml nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add

```
   valid_elements: '*[*]',
```

to *js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js* to allow everything.